# Rails - Active Admin paginating the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, pagination, activeadmin

The Active Admin index page for the Article model in my application takes a very long time to load. This is because there are >2500 article entries, and because I have filters enabled (and I need filters enabled). I feel like I'm already doing everything that the documentation recommends, when it comes to speeding things up, but somehow it's still pulling up every article (when I only want it to pull up the articles on the specific page). That is to say, it seems like pagination is not working properly.

Here's a sampling of the code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
    filter :title
    config.sort_order = "published_desc"
    config.per_page = 10

    index :pagination_total => false do |article|
        # code for my columns goes here
    end
end
```

And here's some relevant output from the log. There are many, many calls of this sort, even when I simply try to search for a single article by title (e.g. using the filter):

```
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (258.8489ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (234.8890ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (269.1431ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (240.3183ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (250.5591ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (403.0311ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=[db_name] collection=articles limit=0 cursor_id=1211541689548427701 (250.7601ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing specific filters often helps to speed up index views. The trouble is ActiveAdmin loads all of the resource's relationships as filter options, many of which might not be required.

#### Remove Unused Filters

Filters can be removed individually using the `remove_filter` method.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  remove_filter :category
end
```

#### Convert to String Filters

Another approach is to change the filter's type. Many times a select isn't necessary to filter by a related record. You could instead define it as a string based filter.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
   # filter :category # <= Slow due to number of categories
   filter :category_name, as: :string
end
```

#### Customize Filter Options

It is also possible to customize what options are available, or only provide a subset of options.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
   filter :category, collection: proc { Category.limit(10) }
end
```